# use attribute of a method into another method

Tags: c#, variables, parameters, methods

how can i use attribute of a method into another method?

for example:
(i commented in related lines)

i have

```
    public int merge()
    {

        string[] source = textBox3.Text.Split(',');

        int[] nums = new int[source.Length];//i want to use nums in mergesort() too,how can i do that?

        for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
        {
            nums[i] = Convert.ToInt32(source[i]);
        }
            }
```

and

```
  public int mergesort()
    {
        if (nums.Length > 1)///i wrote nums here but compiler doesnt know what nums is.
        {
            int n = nums.Length;
            int p = (int)Math.Floor(n / 2.0);
            int m = n - p;
            List<int> lst1 = new List<int>();
            lst1.AddRange(nums.Skip(n / 2));

            List<int> lst2 = new List<int>();
            lst2.AddRange(nums.Take(n / 2));
  }
```

Comment: Attributes have a different meaning in C#...

Comment: Correct use of nomenclature is important to make yourself understood. What nums is in your code is a "variable".

Comment: FYI -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attribute.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define int[] nums at a class level private variable / property

```
private int[] nums = null;

 public int merge() 

  {       
      string[] source = textBox3.Text.Split(','); 
       nums = new int[source.Length];//i want to use nums in mergesort() too,how can i do that?       
        for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)    
           { 
               nums[i] = Convert.ToInt32(source[i]);
           }


    }
```

now use nums in mergesort function .

Comment: @arash: in this example, nums is a "field"

Answer (score 1):

Write

```
public int mergesort(int[] nums)
{
    // ...
}
```

that seems to be the problem.

Comment: i want to use nums that exist in merge(),not a new nums

Comment: are these methods part of the same class?

Comment: @arash: declaring nums as a parameter does not create any new nums. You should learn about [parameters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_(computer_science%29) because they're a very important concept in programming

Comment: ok, than you can call mergesort(nums) in merge() method without problems. the values that contains that array are transfered to the target method without problems.

Answer (score 1):

While a class-level variable *would* work for you, I would recommend sending `nums` as a parameter to `mergesort` because the eventual refactoring would likely dictate the sort be in another class.

```
public int mergesort(int[] nums)
{
    ...
}
```